# Unable to connect to the remote server - due to Driver.Close() and Driver.Quit(), but how to fix?

Tags: c#, selenium

I've been using Selenium and NUnit to do some automated testing, and up until now everything has been fine. The change I made recently was adding more than one test to a test class.

I'm *pretty* certain the issue lies with the code in my "Teardown" function in the test class. When I comment out

```
BrowserFactory.CloseAllDrivers();
```

Things run just fine.

This is the code for my "FrontEndAddItemToCartTest":

```
class FrontEndAddItemToCartTest : PageTest
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            SetBrowser(BrowserFactory.BrowserType.Chrome); // Not headless
            SetServer("testUrlNotGivenForSecurityPurposes");

            StartTest(TestType.FrontEnd);
            SetSize(MobileSize.XXLarge);
        }

        [Test]
        public void StandardQuantityTest()
        {
            OrderItem standardQuantity = new OrderItem(new Product("500", ".25"), 500);
            FrontEndActions.AddItemToCart(standardQuantity);
        }

        [Test]
        public void CustomQuantityTest()
        {
            OrderItem customQuantity = new OrderItem(new Product("482", ".25"), 225);
            FrontEndActions.AddItemToCart(customQuantity);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void EndTest()
        {
            BrowserFactory.CloseAllDrivers();
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

with a bunch of other stuff that I don't believe is relevant.

That being said, I have code in "SetBrowser(...)" that initializes a
`new ChromeDriver();`
but that doesn't seem to be enough.

The methods at the top are there to avoid having to do too much Selenium-y looking stuff in each of the tests - to make things more maintainable by people other than just myself - but it's what you would expect from typical Driver setup. I'm not sure why the second test is what causes the issue, but since things work fine w/o the `CloseAllDrivers()` being run, I'm imagining it's that.

Comment: Are you running the scripts on grid?

Comment: No, I haven't used Selenium Grid at all. The framework I'm making isn't being used in production code yet, it's just something I'm developing while I'm not testing projects. I may make use of Grid once it's 100% official, but until then this is literally me running the tests from Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you please add `driver.Dispose()` in the teardown, after driver.quit() step.

Comment: Yeah I'm at the point where having Dispose() and/or Quit() called works, but as soon as I use Close(), things break. The only problem with either (or both) Quit() &/ Dispose() being used -- the last window open **stays** open for some reason, even though after the first test, the window is closed and the second test opens a fresh window. Not sure why this is. Getting closer.

Comment: Ok, I got your issue. You have to get the windowHandlers and then do `foreach` and close the driver and quit.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the attributes, you're using MSTest? Is it executing tests in parallel?

I guess regardless, for good test isolation you would want to change the CloseAllDrivers method to only dispose the driver used in the test it's cleaning up. I'd recommend starting there and see if that has the same problem.

Also, is CloseAllDrivers calling driver.Quit() or driver.Dispose()? Either of those are the ones you want to use.

Comment: CloseAllDrivers() calls Close() and Quit() -- about to try only having "Dispose()" in there, to see if that changes anything. I read somewhere that Quit already calls Dispose()?

Comment: Also I'm using NUnit, not MSTest - but I feel like that probably doesn't make a difference in this case. Yeah I'm at the point where having Dispose() and/or Quit() called works, but as soon as I use Close(), things break. The only problem with either (or both) Quit() &/ Dispose() being used -- the last window open **stays** open for some reason, even though after the first test, the window is closed and the second test opens a fresh window. Not sure why this is. Getting closer.

Comment: Yeah, Quit() calls Dispose() so they're functionally the same. Close() closes the current window *without* cleaning up the driver, so it can lead to problems. Not sure why they decided to name Close ambiguously. :( 

Based on your other answer, though, glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

OK so the issue was a combination of things:
1. I had `Drivers[driver].Close();` and `Drivers[driver].Quit();` -- only having .Quit() resolved **one** issue. Not really sure why Close() was causing problems, to be quite honest. The other (window not properly closing in the end) was due to the following code in my BrowserFactory:

````
if (driver == null)
{
    Driver = new ChromeDriver((ChromeOptions)options); // options created elsewhere
    Drivers.Add("Chrome", Driver); // This adds the driver to the list of Drivers currently up.
}
else
{
    Driver = new ChromeDriver((ChromeOptions)options); // same as before
    Drivers["Chrome"] = Driver; // **this** wasn't here before. This was the issue. Essentially, I was calling ```Quit()``` on the first instance of the driver, not on the fresh one created by the second test.
}
````

Thanks for all the help, guys. A combination of me determined to figure this out and your responses got me to the solution :)